# case insensitive regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to validate an email address with Regex in C#.

I'm using this pattern:

```
^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$
```

This pattern only matches upper case letters. For example:

"example@gmail.com" -->  returns false.
"EXAMPLE@GMAIL.COM" --> returns true.

I obviously would like that the first example will also return true.

NOTE: I DON'T want to use the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` flag.

I would like to change the pattern itself to match the first example. I think that I can add a "/i" in the end of the pattern or something like this but it doesn't seems to work.
I prefer not to use the "?i" in the beginning as well.

How can i achieve this?

(If you could rewrite the whole pattern for me, it would be great!).

Thanks.

Comment: How is PCRE's `i` modifier any better than .NET's `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`? Is it because it's 22 characters less to type?

Comment: Be careful about the . in the [] block, if you don't want to match any character escape it with a \

Comment: @Johann characters don't need escaping within [] blocks (at least in the .NET regex syntax).

Comment: Be aware that TLD may have more than 4 character long like `travel` or `museum`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Instead of just [A-Z], use [A-Za-z].

But watch out: there are e-mail addresses that end in top-level domains like .travel, that are forbidden according to your regex!

Answer (score 19):

You can just use: `^(?i)[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$`

Notice the `(?i)` which sets the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`, this way you wont have to modify any character classes in the regex or modify where the code is used.

Example (In F# interactive):

```
Regex.Match("test@test.com", @"^(?i)[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$");;
val it : Match = test@test.com {Captures = seq [...];
                              Groups = seq [...];
                              Index = 0;
                              Length = 13;
                              Success = true;
                              Value = "test@test.com";}
```

Comment: I like it - Using the `i` modifier to set `.ignoreCase` is much better than setting `.ignoreCase` in your code. Using the `i` means if your regex is stored in a settings file or database you can change it easily.

Answer (score 6):

Well, this would work.

```
^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$
```